# Can Javascript trigger and populate a native mobile context menu?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, native

The UI library I work on has a pending feature request that involves tapping an in-app button with the intention of triggering a context menu.  On desktop devices, this will simply open our standard context menu.  However, it was requested that on mobile devices, we try to populate and utilize the OS's context menu behavior.

I've read about specific APIs that can trigger native menus, like using a `<select>`, or the `navigator.share()` API for sharing content to other applications.  However, in this case, the web app would need to populate the context menu, and would need to perform app-level behavior upon selecting any of the populated items.

Is there a browser API that can do this on iOS and Android devices?